# How to sort top result on virtual memory on Redhat Linux?

Tags: linux, redhat, top, virtual-memory, sort

There is an interactive key "M" to sort by memory, which seems to be sorting on resident memory. Is there a way to sort on virtual memory? I happen to be working on Redhat Linux, but the question is not specific to this distribution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get a list of things you can sort by by pressing `O`. Virtual segment size is option `o`, so you can get what you want by pressing `Oo<Enter>`.

Answer (score 6):

Try pressing `F` or `O` in top, that should allow you to select the column you want to sort by.

Comment: then hit enter (other keys are possible) to get back to the initial view

Comment: Letter [O], `-mem` or `-vsize`, [enter] works on MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

`top -u test -o VIRT`

Where -u is the users whose processes you are interested in and -o is the field to filter on, yields something like
[image]